# No keys found for HMAC that is valid for time error

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I started having this kind of constant error on my server and I have no idea what is it - did someone have something similar? How can I resolve this?

```
-----------  org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription{address=############-2.service.consul:37752, type=REPLICA_SET_OTHER, state=CONNECTED, ok=true, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=7, maxDocumentSize=16777216, logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=2831751, setName='rs_############', canonicalAddress=############-2.service.consul:37752, hosts=[############-2.service.consul:37752, ############-1.service.consul:37752, ############-0.service.consul:37752], passives=[], arbiters=[], primary='############-0.service.consul:37752', tagSet=TagSet{[]}, electionId=null, setVersion=1, topologyVersion=null, lastWriteDate=Thu May 20 22:55:57 UTC 2021, lastUpdateTimeNanos=2531300430939248}
-----------  [ce.consul:37752] org.mongodb.driver.connection            : Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:65, serverValue:11656453}] to ############-2.service.consul:37752
-----------  [ce.consul:37752] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ############-2.service.consul:37752
-----------  OUT com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 211 (KeyNotFound): 'Cache Reader No keys found for HMAC that is valid for time: { ts: Timestamp(1631194588, 3) } with id: 69#######4408579' on server b33a360#####8-bdd7-9214d51dc498-2.service.consul:37752. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "Cache Reader No keys found for HMAC that is valid for time: { ts: Timestamp(1631194588, 3) } with id: 69841######08579", "code": 211, "codeName": "KeyNotFound"}
-----------  OUT    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
-----------  OUT    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:359) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
-----------  OUT    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receive(InternalStreamConnection.java:305) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
-----------             at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:218) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
-----------  OUT    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.2.jar:na]
-----------  OUT    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: I vaguely remember hearing about this happening if a node was primary for longer than 90 days, but I'm not able to find a reference right now.  Try stepping down or restarting the primary node.

Comment: Only "reliable" reference I could find to this issue is https://mongoing.com/anspress/question/cache-reader-no-keys-found-for-hmac-that-is-valid-for-time , which claims it was fixed in 4.4.3+, but I'm still seeing this in 4.4.8